# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space (just on the server)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, heap-memory

I have an application to upload files. Every time I try to upload a file bigger than few mb (just 1 or 2) i get this error. This happen only when I try to upload file on the server that hosts my site. When I make tests on my computer I have no problems.

I'm sure I close `InputStream`, `BufferedImage` and `Part` Objects every time I finish using them. **Anyway, I get the same error even when I don't close them**.

How can I understand where the problem is? Is there a way or a tool?

The Memory on the server is 64mb

I'll show you the main methods (it would be impossible for you to read and understand all the methods)

In my servlet I get the file uploaded with `request.getPart();` and I put it in a Part field of my object `Immagine`

This is the method `GestioneImmagine`, that call other methods that check if the file is an image and if it's not too big

```
        public void gestioneImmagine(Immagine immagine) throws ImmagineException {

        try {

            //here i call the method the check if the file is a valid image
            if (getImmagineValida(immagine.getImmagineObbligatoria(), immagine.getPart())) {

// if is a "valid file" i  put in my image object a buffered image              
immagine.setImmagineBufferizzata(getImmagineBufferizzata(immagine.getPart().getInputStream()));

                // here i call the method that make 3 resizes for every image
                resizeMultiplo(immagine);
            }

            else {
                immagine.setImmagine(null);
            }           



            if(immagine.getImmagine()!= null){              
                immagine.getImmagine().close();

            }

            if(immagine.getImmagineBufferizzata()!= null){              
                immagine.getImmagineBufferizzata().flush();

            }

            if(immagine.getPart()!= null){              
                immagine.getPart().delete();

            }




        }
        catch (ImmagineException e) {
            throw new ImmagineException("(" + immagine.getDescrizione() + ") " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ImmagineException("Si è verificato un errore durante la gestione dell'immagine: " + e.getMessage());
        }   


    }
```

Here I resize the images, and probably the problem is here. If I dont use this method, I don't have any problem.

```
    public void resizeMultiplo(Immagine immagine) throws ImmagineException {

            String nomeOriginaleDelFile = immagine.getNomeFile();
            int[] dimensioniDasalvare = null; // here i put the 3 sizes, getting the sizes from a static array
            boolean immaginePrincipale = false;

            if (nomeOriginaleDelFile.equalsIgnoreCase(ApplicationInfo.nomeImmaginePrincipale)) {
                dimensioniDasalvare = ApplicationInfo.formatiImmaginePrincipale;
                immaginePrincipale = true;
            }

            else {
                dimensioniDasalvare = ApplicationInfo.formatiImmagineClassica; 
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dimensioniDasalvare.length; i++) {

                try {

                    // i set the width of the image
                    immagine.setLarghezza(dimensioniDasalvare[i]);  


// here i make some test to understand  how to rename the file and which of the 3 sizes i have to use

                    if (dimensioniDasalvare[i] == ApplicationInfo.maxWidthImage) {
                        immagine.setNomeFile(nomeOriginaleDelFile);
                    } else if (immaginePrincipale) {


                        if (dimensioniDasalvare[i] == 500) {
                            immagine.setNomeFile(ApplicationInfo.nomeImmaginePrincipale);
                        } else {
                            immagine.setNomeFile(dimensioniDasalvare[i] + ApplicationInfo.separatoreTraDimensioneFotoENome
                                    + ApplicationInfo.nomeImmaginePrincipale);


                            immagine.setImmagineBufferizzata(getThumbnailQuadrato(immagine));
                        }

                    } else {
                        immagine.setNomeFile(dimensioniDasalvare[i] + ApplicationInfo.separatoreTraDimensioneFotoENome
                                + nomeOriginaleDelFile);

                        immagine.setImmagineBufferizzata(getThumbnailQuadrato(immagine));
                    }




                    if (immagine.getImmagineBufferizzata().getWidth() > dimensioniDasalvare[i]) {

                        immagine.setImmagineBufferizzata(getBufferedImageResized(immagine));

                    }





                    //here i call the method that write the file on filesystem
                    scriviImmagine(immagine);
                }
                catch(ImmagineException e){
                    throw new ImmagineException(e.getMessage());                
                }
                catch(MyFileException e){
                    throw new ImmagineException(e.getMessage());                
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new ImmagineException("Si è verificato un errore durante il salvataggio su disco dell'immagine " + immagine.getNomeFile() + ": " + e.getMessage());

                }





            }

            immagine.setNomeFile(nomeOriginaleDelFile);
            immagine.setImmagineBufferizzata(null);
            immagine.setImmagine(null);

        }
    }
```

This is the error

```
Exception in thread "http-bio-12418-exec-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(DataBufferInt.java:75)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:467)
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1032)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:331)
    at JeansEdizioni.Funzioni.ImmagineFunzioni.getBufferedImageResized(ImmagineFunzioni.java:148)
    at JeansEdizioni.Funzioni.ImmagineFunzioni.resizeMultiplo(ImmagineFunzioni.java:622)
    at JeansEdizioni.Funzioni.ImmagineFunzioni.gestioneImmagine(ImmagineFunzioni.java:397)
    at JeansEdizioni.Controller.ArtistiController.inserisciArtista(ArtistiController.java:244)
    at JeansEdizioni.Controller.ArtistiController.doPost(ArtistiController.java:307)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at JeansEdizioni.Filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Showing the code that is called when the stack happens would be a good first step.

Comment: How much RAM is dedicated to your application in the server? Is there a big difference between this and the RAM you designate in your dev environment?

Comment: My first assumption (or more of a guess) would be that you are trying to load the entire file at once. However, I have no idea since I don't have any code, so please post it.

Comment: have you tried to increase heap manually ?

Comment: I edited my post, dunno if it's easy to understand

Comment: @J4v4 i load the entire file at once. How should i do?

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali You send chunks of 1024-10000 bytes. I would like to see the sending process.

Comment: You need to stream the image data instead of sending one giant byte[].

Comment: @J4v4 what should i do? I dont understand what you are saying to me.  Every example i read use the getPart() method to get a file. After getting it, what should i do?

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the classes you are using for your server. Taking a quick look into the documentation of Part, it seems to me that a Part is constructed by reading the entire request and storing the file in an object, that is your application's memory. In order to work around this, you have to write the data DIRECTLY to a file from the request, e.g. you read a chunk from the request and write it to a file, so you never have a file in your memory. As I said, Part seems to read the entire file, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Im not sure i understood. Let's make an example. when the user upload and image, i should save it straight away on file system, and then use this file in my file system to check the size, to resize it etc?